# Three.js – Create half a ring and animate it

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, ring

I've created a Ring and would like to have only half of it. And after that animate it, that it builds itself up from 0 to half.

```js
var geometry = new THREE.RingGeometry(10, 9, 32);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xffff00,
  side: THREE.DoubleSide,
});
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);
```

How can I archive it? I'm new to three.js.

Comment: `RingGeometry()` / `RingBufferGeometry()` have `thetaStart` and `thetaLength` parameters. Bur for animation, you have to re-build a geometry on each frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `thetaStart` and `thetaLength` to animate the half-ring.

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.118.3/build/three.module.js";

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 100);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var grid = new THREE.GridHelper(10, 10);
grid.rotation.x = Math.PI * 0.5;
scene.add(grid);

var innerRadius = 1;
var outerRadius = 2;

// re-building geometry
var usualRingGeom = new THREE.RingBufferGeometry(innerRadius, outerRadius, 32, 1, 0, 1);
var usualRingMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffff00});
var usualRing = new THREE.Mesh(usualRingGeom, usualRingMat);
scene.add(usualRing);

var clock = new THREE.Clock();

renderer.setAnimationLoop(()=>{
  let t = clock.getElapsedTime();
  
  // re-building geometry
  usualRingGeom = new THREE.RingBufferGeometry(innerRadius, outerRadius, 32, 1, 0, (Math.sin(t) * 0.5 + 0.5) * Math.PI);
  usualRing.geometry.dispose();
  usualRing.geometry = usualRingGeom;
  
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});
</script>
```

PS You also can achieve the same result without re-building a geometry. For that, you can bend a plane in js (changing vertices) or in shaders :)